# Google Web Toolkit - UiBinder with CSS styling

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder

I am new in GWT. Here is my questions:

Form.css

```
.text{
color: orange;
font-size: 16pt;}
```

FormResources.java

```
public interface FormResources extends ClientBundle{

@Source("Form.css")
MyCSS style();

public interface MyCSS extends CssResource{
    String text();
}}
```

Form.ui.xml

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
         xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
         xmlns:res="urn:with:com.org.yournamehere.client.FormResources">

<ui:with field='res' type='org.yournamehere.client.FormResources' />

<g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:Label res:styleName="style.text">ABC</g:Label>
</g:HTMLPanel></ui:UiBinder>
```

Form.java

```
public class Form extends Composite {

private static final FormUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(FormUiBinder.class);

@UiTemplate("Form.ui.xml")
interface FormUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, Form> {}

@UiField(provided = true)
final FormResources res;

public Form() {
    this.res = GWT.create(FormResources.class);
    res.style().ensureInjected();
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
}}
```

My problem is can show the ABC word, but not in orange color and size is 16pt. The Css part cannot shown. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't your assets filenames be written in lowercase? Like form.css, instead of Form.css. That won't solve the problem though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost doing right.

Just replace below line in `Form.ui.xml` file.

```
<g:Label res:styleName="style.text">ABC</g:Label>
```

with

```
<g:Label res:styleName="{res.style.text}">ABC</g:Label>
```

screenshot:

[image]

---

Problem : `"style.text"` is not referring to your style defined in `FormResources#MyCSS#text`.

Always enclose the value in `{...}` if you want to use some dynamic values.

For more info have a look at sample on [GWT UiBinder - Hello Stylish World](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Hello_Stylish_World)